# using argparse to read in a delimited string of numbers in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I am trying to pass from the command line a delimited string of numbers including negative numbers using argparse.

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-l","--list",help="delimited string input",type=str)
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

When I run the code using:

```
python3 prog.py -l "-1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,-1"
```

I get:

```
usage: camWithFilterDemo.py [-h] [-l LIST]
camWithFilterDemo.py: error: argument -l/--list: expected one argument
```

Can anyone help with a solution or other options I should look into or consider.

Comment: The problem is that `-1` is being treated as an option, but I'm not sure the best way to fix it. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want advice.

Comment: An extra space at the start of that string is an easy fix: python3 prog.py -l " -1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,-1".  Obviously it isn't a robust or user friendly choice, but it's the simplest patch.

Comment: The duplicate isn't idea, since it focuses on accepting a negative scientific notation.  I'm sure there are newer duplicates that address the same issue.  In any case argument strings which start with a '-' are a problem with `argparse`.  It's a known issue without a easy fix.